# read analog value from xbee (non serially)

Tags: arduino, xbee

I'm trying to send an analog value from xbee to another xbee (WHICH IS CONNECTED TO ARDUINO). But I don't want to read this value serially (`x=Serial.read();`).

I would like to read this value from an arduino's analog input (`x=analogRead(A0);`). Can I pass an analog value from 1st xbee input pin to 2nd xbee output pin and connect this pin with ex.arduino's analog input (A0) and process it? If it can be done, how does this occur? (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed possible. Xbee's have DAC and digital line support. Check out the user manual found in this [Manual](ftp://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000982_A.pdf)

The information you're going to need is on page 12. This is for series one xbee's.

For series two xbee's the process is different and can be found in this manual
[manual](ftp://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000866_C.pdf) on page 41. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect you would be better off using xbee API and just do an AT command to read pin, then transfer it over serial TX out to the arduino RX in.